# Python itertools: how to print permutations as a vertical list

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools, iterable

I am trying to get the output as a vertical list but don´t know which value to use at the place of the iterable? I only need to see the 6 values in all possible orders.

see the code below. thanks for the help.

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.permutations(['1 Download the App and create an app account', '2 Choose the station on the map or by searching on the station name in the search field', '3 choose connector', '4 Choose payment method, and process the payment of the pre-authorization fee', '5 Connect the cable to vehicle to start charging', '6 Review the price tariff and click on Start Charging'], 6)))
print(*iterable, sep = '\n')
```

Comment: `x = itertools.permutations...` `print(*x, sep = '\n')`?

Answer (score 0):

For instance like this:

```
myList = ['1 Download the App and create an app account', '2 Choose the station on the map or by searching on the station name in the search field', '3 choose connector', '4 Choose payment method, and process the payment of the pre-authorization fee', '5 Connect the cable to vehicle to start charging', '6 Review the price tariff and click on Start Charging']

for p in itertools.permutations(myList, 6):
    print(*p, sep='\n')
    print()
```